Basis of the decomposition of two commutating groups
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
Consider the following representations of the permutation group $S_n$ and the unitary group $U(d)$ acting on the vector space $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ like:
$$
P(s)\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes\ket{\psi_n}=\ket{\psi_{s^{-1}(1)}}\otimes...\otimes \ket{\psi_{s^{-1}(n)}}\hspace{1em} (s\in S_n)
$$
and
$$
Q(U)\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes\ket{\psi_n}=U\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes U\ket{\psi_n}\hspace{1em} (U\in U(d)).
$$
Both of these representations can be decomposed into irreducible representations:
$$
P(s)\cong\bigoplus_\alpha\mathbb{I}_{n_\alpha}\otimes\pi_\alpha(s)
$$
and
$$
Q(U)\cong\bigoplus_\beta\mathbb{I}_{m_\beta}\otimes q_\beta(U).
$$
Here, $n_\alpha$ and $m_\beta$ are the multiplicities of the irreps $\pi_\alpha(s)$ and $q_\beta(U)$. Now I read that the same basis, decomposing $P(s)$ into irreps is the same basis, decomposing $Q(U)$. According to the reference I read (Jordi Tura i Brugués, Characterizing Entanglement and Quantum Correlations Constrained by Symmetry, Appendix A.2), it is stated that this can be followed from Schur's Lemma. Is this true and if so, how can this be proven?

This is a bit imprecise but it sounds like you're talking about Schur-Weyl duality. Searching with that keyword should bring up a lot of sources; you can see a discussion, for example, in this old blog post of mine, which follows Section 4.18 of Etingof's notes on representation theory.
